# Chrome extension deployment don't work since July 2022

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I hade a working deployment and publishing for a Chrome extension. Since July 2022 this deployment doesn't work anymore but i have no idea why i not work.

The current deployment work with the oauth2 auth from google.

To check what could be the problem i try to open the auth-url with my client-id

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore&client_id=$%7BCLIENT_ID%7D&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

But there i'll get always the same error
[image]

I try to create a new deployment from scretch with the google tutorial but there is still the same error (i guess they dont update the tutorial correctly).

Have anyone an idea what is the problem or how i can find the problem?

Comment: Is that tutorial https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/? If so, its "scopes":[""] is wrong.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto a little bit deeper you find the next step with scopes